# Passing parameters to Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

This my view in ruby on rails.I need to make call to removeHistory function when the image is clicked

```
<div class=float-right>
<img  src="/images/active_star.png" onclick="removeHistory('<%= detail.message%>')" />
</div
```

And my script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeHistory(text){
      alert(text);
    }
</script>
```

This works fine when details.message contains no single or double quotes. What I need to do, to make single or double quotes to work?

Comment: you could use escape symbol on it like this may be:
"this is \" quoted text \" lorem ipsum"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<%= j detail.message %>
```

or

```
<%= escape_javascript detail.message %>
```

I not sure that j is alias for escape_javascript in Rails < 4

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

Replace single quots with `&#039`;   and  double quotes with  `&quot;`